# Is there anyway to detect user inactivity in java?

Tags: java, user-inactivity

I am writing a desktop application in which I want to perform an operation if user doesn't use the computer for X number of minutes. Just like auto idle in MSN messager or skype. Any hints?

Comment: *"if user doesn't use the computer for X number of minutes."*  The computer or the application?  The latter is what MSN & Skype do, and it is much easier than monitoring the entire computer, beside being more the apps. business (to know).

Comment: I am talking about the computer input and I think MSN and skype detects computer input rather than application input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found https://code.google.com/p/fiat-lux/source/browse/Fiat+Lux/src/fiatlux/os/time/ that served my purpose.

Thanks

Comment: This time code looks like it's actually from the jppf project originally. The gradle artifact that contains this code is at 'org.jppf:jppf-node:5.1.1' and you can find the source from the same http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jppf/jppf-node/5.0/org/jppf/node/idle/IdleTimeDetectorFactoryImpl.java?av=f

It's worth noting that the JPPF code is under Apache 2.0 and the Fiat-Lux code linked above is under GPL, although possibly incorrectly so.

Answer (score 3):

you need to:

- listen for events at the application level
- track the time interval between these events

read [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) this article. you have the code under *InactivityListener.java*

And there is even a similar thread: [How to detect inactivity/idle time since last keypressed on j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132190/how-to-detect-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-keypressed-on-j2me)

Comment: Consider changing "track the time interval" (sounds like a report), to "have a thread that periodically wakes up and checks for absence of events"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a background thread that basically only sleeps idle or a [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) task if you are not already using any timer/job scheduler library.

Comment: Isn't this restricted to your application, in contrast to foreign applications, running on the machine?